# How to execute parallel commands

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, ubuntu, zsh

Im working on large project and we have multiple `npm packages`.

I want to install all the packages in parallel which mean that i want all of to run on the same time (to save time) and once the last install has finished to continue with my script.

#### Example script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
#...

NPM_FOLDERS=(
    common.library/audit
    common.library/cipher
    common.library/logger
    ...
)

# Get the number of total folders to process
counter=${#NPM_FOLDERS[@]};

# counter for user feedback to the current install folder index
index=1;

# loop and install all the required packages
for folder in $NPM_FOLDERS;
do 
    #  Print the installation message with the folder & couters
    echo "\033[38;5;255m($index/$counter) Executing npm install in: \033[38;5;226m$folder";
    
    # change the folder to the required location    
    cd $ROOT_FOLDER/$folder;
    
    # Execute install on this folder
    npm install ;
   
    # increase current index
    let index++;

done

echo
echo "\033[38;5;11mInstallation completed."
echo
```

In not going to accept the fastest answer but the one who will do what i wish to do and do not have the right knowledge on how to do it, so you can tale the time and give a full answer.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `npm install &`? Not sure how to explicitly wait for background processes, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute `npm install` in the background with:

```
npm install &
```

Then after the `done` line you can wait for all the background processes to finish with:

```
wait
```

This command is explained in the [`bash manual`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-wait):

> Wait until the child process specified by each process ID pid or job specification jobspec exits and return the exit status of the last command waited for. If a job spec is given, all processes in the job are waited for. If no arguments are given, **all currently active child processes are waited for**, and the return status is zero.

Comment: But this will not wait until the last one will install. i need to install 20+ process and wait until the last one will finish. will it work?

Comment: What will the wait do? will it wait for all the processes?

Comment: If you run `wait` with no arguments, it waits for all background processes.

Comment: Why would you assume I was wrong, instead of reading the documentation and confirming that what I wrote would work as you want?

Comment: Not assuming you are wrong. just trying to understand what is it doing. I appropriate it. just trying to understand it

Comment: It's working like a charm.


Thank  you very much,

Comment: What does the wait do at the end? i understand its waiting for all the process, is there place where i can read about it to learn how it works?

Comment: Appropriate your help, accepted and voted for your answer. Can you please explain what the wait does in few words?

Comment: It waits for all background processes to finish, just like I said in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, i learned something new thanks to you,

Comment: I've added an excerpt from the documentation, because you don't know how to google.

Comment: Thank you, Have a great new year.